# How to fetch JSON array in Retrofit?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array inside which there are `JSON Objects` like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "63",
        "userprofile": "userprofile.jpg",
        "username": "James",
        "content": "test.",
        "address": "1111 Parker St",
        "Post_date": "2022-05-25 02:41:15",
        "images": [
            "20220525_0241291.jpg",
            "20220525_0241290.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to have the string elements in the `images` array as objects instead. Can anyone suggest me how to make this type of JSON?

```json
[
    {
        "id": "63",
        "userprofile": "userprofile.jpg",
        "username": "James",
        "content": "test.",
        "address": "1111 Parker St",
        "Post_date": "2022-05-25 02:41:15",
        "images": [
            {"image": "20220525_0241291.jpg"},
            {"image": "20220525_0241290.jpg"}
         ]
    }
]
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

header("Content-Type:application/json");
include '../db_con.php'; 

$query = "SELECT Board.* , 
                GROUP_CONCAT(Board_images.imagepath separator ',') AS multiimages 
            FROM Board                       
                LEFT JOIN Board_images ON Board.index = Board_images.boardindex 
            GROUP BY Board.index 
            ORDER BY Board.index";  

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 

$response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    array_push(
        $response,
        array(
            'id' => $row['index'], 
            'userprofile' => $row['userprofile'], 
            'username' => $row['username'], 
            'content' => $row['content'], 
            'address' => $row['address'], 
            'Post_date' => $row['Post_date'], 
            'images' => explode(',',$row['multiimages']) 
            
        )
    );
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Note I removed the additional question about android stuff, it's not related to the PHP at all and questions need to be focused on one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`explode` returns a simple array of strings. All you have to do is go over it and put each of those strings into an array. You can do this in a loop or using an [array function like `array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) which will do the same thing, applying a callback to each item.

You also don't need a loop to populate your response array, instead use [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all). You could use a loop to add the extra `images` element, but again I prefer using [the `array_walk()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) as a matter of personal opinion.

(The difference between `array_map` and `array_walk` is that `array_map` returns a new array based on what the callback returns. `array_walk` only modifies the existing array.)

```php
<?php
include '../db_con.php'; 

$query = "SELECT Board.* , GROUP_CONCAT(Board_images.imagepath separator ',') AS multiimages FROM Board                       
LEFT JOIN Board_images ON Board.index = Board_images.boardindex GROUP BY Board.index ORDER BY Board.index";  

$result = $con->query($query); 

// fetch all the records at once
$response = $result->fetch_all(\MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// this performs similar function to a foreach loop
array_walk(
    $response,
    function (&$v, $k) {
        // explode the comma-separated list into an indexed array
        $images = explode(",", $v["multiimages"]);
        // now turn it into a bunch of associative arrays
        $images = array_map(fn ($im) => ["image" => $im], $images);
        // and then add it to the original $response array
        $v["images"] = $images;
    }
);

header("Content-Type:application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
```